# gnuplot: how to put two figures side by side

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to put two figures side by side using gnuplot with multiplot.
I want the resulting image to be rectangular so I use set size 2, 1. I also set the set multiplot layout 1, 2 option. However, the resulting image only uses the left part of the available space. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
Ahmet

Here is the resulting image
http://tinypic.com/r/33mlz04/6

And below is the gnuplot commands I'm using.

```
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced
set output 'figure.eps'; 
set size 2,1;

set multiplot layout 1, 2 ;
set title "Figure 1";
  plot  "data1.txt" 
set title "Figure 1";
 plot  "data2.txt" 
unset multiplot
```

Although I'm not very sure, with some trial and error I have solved it

```
    set terminal postscript eps color enhanced 

    set output 'eps/image.eps'; 
    set size 1,0.5;

    set multiplot layout 1, 2 ;
    set title "Figure 1";
    set size 0.5,0.5;
    plot  "data/data1.txt" 
    set title "Figure 1";
    set size 0.5,0.5;
    plot  "data/data2.txt" 
    unset multiplot
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As a matter of style, you don't need trailing semicolons in gnuplot (as you would in C) ... while they don't hurt, they tend to make the script a little less readible (IMHO).  Also, if you found the solution by @andyras useful, feel free to upvote or even mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 11):

Try something like:

```
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced size 10,5
set output 'figure.eps';

set multiplot layout 1, 2 ;
set title "Figure 1";
plot  "data1.txt" 
set title "Figure 1";
plot  "data2.txt" 
unset multiplot
```

When you set the size on the terminal specification line, that determines the actual size of the plot canvas (in inches in this case).  When you use `set size` on a separate line, that sets the size of the plot in relative units of the canvas size.  This is different in older versions of gnuplot.  For perhaps a better explanation, try `help set size` in gnuplot.

Comment: Thanks andyras, although what you have suggested doesn't work, it led me to try further possibilities, and I managed to solve the problem. I put the solution under the original post.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem.  The solution I posted works for me--which version of gnuplot are you using?

Comment: Good job pointing out the difference between the size of the "canvas" and the size of the individual plots.  (+1)

Answer (score 4):

For even more control over the size/position of the plot, you can use `set origin` in conjuction with `set size` to change the placement and size of each plot.  Finally, the most control can be achieved with `set lmargin at <place>` (and `set rmargin ...`) and so-on for `tmargin` and `bmargin` where the "lrtb" stand for left, right, top and bottom respectively.

So, to get a plot to fill all of the available space (left to right), you could:

```
set multiplot
set lmargin at 0
set rmargin at .5
plot sin(x)
set lmargin at .5
set rmargin at 1
plot cos(x)
unset multiplot
```

However, this is (usually) overkill.  Usually gnuplot tries to make the margins big enough for your labels and such, but setting the margin explicitly disables that.  I would suggest you go with the solution by andyras.

Answer (score 1):

if you are having problems using this method for more than 2 figures add 'set origin 0,0' after 'set size 0.5,0.5'.
For example, for three figures :

```
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced 

set output 'eps/image.eps'; 
set size 1.5,0.5;

set multiplot layout 1, 3 ;
set title "Figure 1";
set size 0.5,0.5;
set origin 0,0
plot  "data/data1.txt" 
set title "Figure 2";
set size 0.5,0.5;
set origin 0,0
plot  "data/data3.txt"
set title "Figure 3";
set size 0.5,0.5;
set origin 0,0
plot  "data/data3.txt" 
unset multiplot
```